# How do you specify POST params in a Rails test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, shoulda

Working with Test::Unit and Shoulda. Trying to test `Users.create`. My understanding is that Rails forms send params for an object like this:

```
user[email]
```

Which turns into hash in your action, right?

```
params[:user][:email]
```

OK, so in my test I've tried...

```
setup { post :create, :post => { 'user[email]' => 'invalid@abc' } }
```

and

```
setup { post :create, :post => { :user => { :email => 'abc@abcd' } } }
```

In both cases, over in my action, `params[:user]` is nil.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
post :create, :user => { :email => 'foo@bar.com' }
```

The general form for all the test methods of get, post, put, delete are as follows:

```
def post(action_name, params_hash = {}, session_hash = {})
```

And in tests, the params hash gets directly sent into `params` of your controller action with no translation of any sort.  Even doing integration testing you really shouldnt need to test this string to params translation as its covered very well by the rails framework tests.  Plus all testing methods that need params accept a hash in this manner without complaint making things easy for you.

Comment: this also is gonna work : "post :create, { :email => 'foo@bar.com' }" and from the controller side you will have: params[:email] gives you 'foo@bar.com'

Answer (score 8):

```
post :create, {:post => {}, :user => {:email => 'abc@abcd'} }
```

In this case params[:post] is {}, 
params[:user] is {:email => 'abc@abcd'},
params[:user][:email] is 'abc@abcd'.

```
post :create, {:post => {:user => {:email => 'abc@abcd'} } }
```

In this case params[:post][:user][:email] is 'abc@abcd'