# Rails - howto setup a test that posts to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm still a rails newbie, and am looking to learn how to write a unit/functional test. not exactly sure which is best.

I'm writing a controller that parses a POST request. So what I'd like to do is write a test that posts to my controller so I can get the controller setup.

In Rails, whats the right way to get started with this?

I want the post to be a multipart/form-data request with the several parameters like message, subject, from, etc...

Thanks

Comment: Possible help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529653/how-do-you-specify-post-params-in-a-rails-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails provides functional tests for this, unit tests are usually for models

You could look at using the rspec_rails gem also, it provides generators for that kind of thing i believe:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails